# how can I use var out of model.find(), Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to use var `bot_man` how can I pass to out of function.

```js
var bot_man = ''
  Post.find({ title: 'bot_status' }, function (err, author) {
    if (err) throw err
    bot_man = author[0].body
    console.log(author[0].body) //output => 'on'
  })
  console.log(`result = ${bot_man}`) // result =
```

result is ''
`result =`

Comment: You need to learn how to deal with asynchrony ... the result is guaranteed to ONLY be available inside the callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Post.find` is an asynchronous function. When you [call it it with a callback](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.find) it defers callback's execution untill the result is ready (somewhere in the future) and immediatelly proceeds to the next line. Thus `bot_man` is still an empty string when evaluated in `console.log('result = ${bot_man}')`.

To get the result you'd better off making your function [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and rewrite it as:

```js
let author = await Post.find({ title: 'bot_status' }).exec()
let bot_man = author[0].body

console.log(`result = ${bot_man}`)
```

Though for production code it still lacks some sanity checks. Whether `author` is not null or empty and error handling. I didn't include them into the snippet to not complicate the code.

Comment: I need at least 15 reputations to cast a vote. thank you, man <3